What's the name of the form of the song "12 Days of Christmas"?
What's the name of the form of the song 12 Days of Christmas, or the "style" of the composition, where a new "verse" is accumulated as follows:

A
BA
CBA
DCBA
EDCBA
FEDCBA
GFEDCBA
HGFEDCBA
IHGFEDCBA
JIHGFEDCBA
KJIHGFEDCBA
LKJIHGFEDCBA

?

Maybe a more appropriate word is the "form" instead of "style", with the tag musical-forms instead of styles ?

99 Bottles of Beer on the Wall could be another example.

Shouldn't it be A - BA - CBA ... ?

Might be better known as 10 green bottles, hanging on the wall. 99 would take all night to sing!

@the-baby-is-you Indeed — though it's a lot more complicated than that.  (Isn't everything?!)  More accurately, I think it would be AB - ACB - ACCB - ACCCB - ADB - ACDB - ACCDB - ACCCDB - ACCCCDB - ACCCCCDB - ACCCCCCDB - ACCCCCCCDB.  (And if there's a name for that specific form — other than ‘the form of “The Twelve Days Of Christmas”’ — then I'll buy you all a mince pie!)

@the-baby-is-you I've implemented your correction.

@gidds I don't understand your version. Could you please explain it more?

@gidds isn’t quite right, but they’re probably referring to the fact that most (all?) of the verses past 5 are all melodically basically the same and almost the same rhythmically too. So it’s not 12 distinct lines, musically

The words accumulate in the obvious way, but the music only does so if you treat the first four days separately from the rest.  To describe all the music together, I was using A = the music for “On the first day of Christmas, my true love gave to me”, B = “…(and) a partridge in a pear tree.”, C = the short phrase used (with slight variations) for most of the numbers, and D = all of “…give gold rings; four calling birds, three French hens, two turtle doves” (with different music for 4, 3, and 2).  (cont…)

…I think that's accurate (if you allow for the ‘and’ being omitted from B the first time through, and for all the slight variations in C) — and I also think it's about the most concise way to describe it accurately.

It's literally called Cumulative song.  See Wikipedia for numerous examples.
